# Azure Subscription Policies

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I would need to create a policy in subscription level contributor cannot able to create virtual machines and virtual network or any vnets. Only owner are able to create Vnets. How to do this

Comment: Did that help you?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might need to create a custom role.

You can add various roles using RBAC for Access management of cloud resources.

The following document has the information on all the built-in roles in Azure RBAC: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles

If built-in roles do not fulfill your requirements, you can also use create your own custom roles using PowerShell:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/tutorial-custom-role-powershell

Here is the Azure doc on understanding various roles and create in Azure portal:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles